# Question about finding the number of zeros in the first quadrant.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a homework problem asking me to determine the number of zeros in the first quadrant. 
http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~iron/math5020/hw2sol.pdf

That's not my homework, but it has a similar problem.

1. I am confused where it says that the critical point of $f(x)$ is $1$. How did they arrive at that conclusion?
2. Why does $\operatorname{Arg}(f(z))$ go from $0$ to $3\pi/2$ along $\gamma_2$?
3. Along $\gamma_3$, how do we know that $\operatorname{Im}(f(z)) < 0$?
4. Lastly, why does the total change in argument equal $2\pi$?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Regarding 1: Along the curve $\gamma_1$, it follows that $f(z) = f(x) = x^3 - 3x + 6$ is a polynomial in a single real variable. Differentiating gives

$$f'(x) = 3x^2 - 3$$

For x to be a critical point, it must be a root of $f'$ - the only such roots are $x = \pm 1$.

Regarding 2: The $z^3$ term dominates, especially for large $R$. If we write $z = e^{i \theta}$, then $z^3 = e^{i (3\theta)}$; hence, a change in argument for $z$ induces three times as much change in $z^3$.

Regarding 3: Write $z = iy$, expand and collect terms. Observe that the imaginary part is negative for $y$ positive. Likewise, see that the real part is positive.

Regarding 4: After $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, the argument of $f$ has changed by $3\pi/2$. By (3), f(z) remains in the fourth quadrant along $\gamma_3$, but $f(0) = 6$ is real. Hence, the argument can't have looped more than $2\pi$, nor less than $3\pi/2$.

Comment: Regarding 2: So if the question was asking for the number of zeros over the first two quadrants, then the change in argument would be 3 x pi, is that right? Regarding 4, it's the maximum change in argument possible given the conditions in the problem?

Comment: Regarding 3, if the real part is something like 1-2y, then is that positive or negative? I don't know what the values of y are supposed to be.